# how to use libgit2 to get a SHA value when i want to commit a new file to git

Tags: ios, sha, libgit2

how to use libgit2 to get a SHA value when i want to commit a new file to git
The command in shell is:

```
git add
git commit
git pull
git push
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following **libgit2** tests should get you started:

- **[commitstagedfile.c](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/development/tests-clar/object/commit/commitstagedfile.c)**: how to `git add` a file to the staging area, then perform a `git commit` and retrieve the sha of the created commit.
- **[fetch.c](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/development/tests-clar/online/fetch.c)**: how to `git fetch` and update the content of the local repository with upstream changes
- **[push.c](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/development/tests-clar/online/push.c)**: how to submit the local changes to the upstream repository, similarly to `git push`

**Note:** `git pull` is a combination of `git fetch` and `git merge`. The merging capabilities are not available yet in libgit2.

Comment: In commitstagedfile.c, it get oid from str.(git_oid_fromstr(&expected_commit_oid, "1fe3126578fc4eca68c193e4a3a0a14a0704624d")). I have already have a git dir, but I dont know how to get (const git_tree *tree) when I use git_commit_create instead of test hex value.  Can you explain the process of this, thx

Comment: The tree is being **[created in the object database](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/development/tests-clar/object/commit/commitstagedfile.c#L101-104)** from the index. In order to pass it to the git_commit_creat_v() method, it's first **[retrieved from the object database](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/development/tests-clar/object/commit/commitstagedfile.c#L112)**.

Comment: Thx :) I got it. I am a beginner using libgit2. Here is my thought at beginning, can you tell me what I have thought wrong? First, build a blob using git_blob_create_fromworkdir, secondly, git_treebuilder_create and git_tree_entry to create a tree builder, then use git_treebuilder_write to write the content, and use git_tree_lookup to got the git_tree?